# Flex space around does not respond

Tags: html, css

HTML CODES
I cannot use 'space-around' property.It does not work even if I wrap tag 'a' and 'svg' with div.How can I solve this problem?

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
}

.title {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: space-around;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">
    <a href="#">Library</a>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-bookmark"><path d="M19 21l-7-5-7 5V5a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h10a2 2 0 0 1 2 2z"></path></svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `flex-direction: space-around` is incorrect. You have to use `justify-content` property: `justify-content:space-around`

Comment: Yes you are right I used as you write. But it does not still work

Comment: `justify-content: space-around` works fine for me. Can you update your question with the code you're using, and elaborate on what the problem is?

Comment: `justify-content: space-around` is the correct syntax and flex-direction property specifies the direction of the flexible items.

Comment: I understand my problem.Thank you for your comment:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Sfili mentioned in the comments, those styles correspond with `justify-content` and not `flex-direction`. `space-around` is supposed to give the elements equal spacing on both sides. So if you had a `300px` container. `space-around` would look like so:

[image]

`space-between` on the other hand will space the elements on both ends of the parent. So it would space both items to the start and end of their parent. See below.

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  outline: solid black 1px;
}

.title {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">
    <a href="#">Library</a>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-bookmark"><path d="M19 21l-7-5-7 5V5a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h10a2 2 0 0 1 2 2z"></path></svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I understand my problem.I used the align-property.Thank you for your respond.It helped me a lot:)